# Windows 8 not remembering to project on second screen

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I've set up my Windows 8 notebook to project only on a second screen that's connected with VGA. This works perfectly fine, but whenever I reboot (and yes: I do have the VGA cable connected before I boot it up), it defaults back to the notebook's screen.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to reinitialize the monitors data from scratch by deleting in the registry all the keys under :

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration\
```

and then reboot.

Export this key first just in case, and even better - create a system restore point.

Comment: After a few days of testing, this definetely worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue related to your graphics driver. I would suggest downloading the latest driver from the manufacturer's web-site, uninstall the current driver, and install the new driver making sure to select *Clean Installation* if the option is available.